# Output an element the number of times I want

Tags: list, haskell

I have this code:

```
lado ::  [([Char],Int)] -> [[Char]]
lado xs = [a | (a,b) <- xs]
```

I need to output this:

```
> lado [("A",3),("B",2),("C",1)]
["A","B","C","A","B","A"]
```

I have to output "A" 3 times, then "B" 2 times then "C" 1 time but I only get this ["A","B","C"] with this code.

Comment: Hint: first start with `["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C"]`, then you can transpose the result.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I don't think I can do that. I need this ["A","B","C","A","B","A"] to zip with another list of charts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already use list comprehensions in your attempt. Use them some more.

```
lado ::  [([Char],Int)] -> [[Char]]
lado xs = [a | (a,b) <- xs, b <- [1..b]]
```

testing:

```
> lado [("A",3),("B",2),("C",1)]
["A","A","A","B","B","C"]
```

As your question is saying,

> I have to output "A" 3 times, then "B" 2 times then "C" 1 time

But if it is really `["A","B","C","A","B","A"]` you want, then

```
lado ::  [(a,Int)] -> [a]
lado []        = []
lado ((a,1):b) = a : lado b
lado ((a,n):b) = a : lado (b ++ [(a,n-1))])
```

which can be coded with `unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]` from `Data.List`,

```
lado ::  [(a,Int)] -> [a]
lado xs = unfoldr g $ xs
  where
  g []        = Nothing
  g ((a,1):b) = Just (a, b)
  g ((a,n):b) = Just (a, b ++ [(a,n-1)])
```

which can be emulated with Prelude's `iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]` etc., as

```
lado ::  [(a,Int)] -> [a]
lado xs = map (fst . head) . takeWhile ( ... ) . iterate g $ xs
  where
  g []            = []
  g ((a, ... ):b) = b
  g ((a,  n  ):b) = b ++ [(a, ... )]
```

Testing:

```
> lado [("A",3),("B",2),("C",1)]
["A","B","C","A","B","A"]
```

Fill in the blanks `...` to make it work.

---

as [@dfeuer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1477667/dfeuer) notes, the repeated singleton-appending at list's end is detrimental to overall efficiency. With big thanks to his input and discussion, including the two answers and comments here and even a github [gist](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/86dd2cd8fd0808626dbff52ea5146c7c), this can be remedied by the usual FP paradigm (not to say "trick") of building a list in reverse, as

```
lado ::  [(a,Int)] -> [a]
lado xs = go (filter ((> 0) . snd) xs) []
  where
  go []       []  =  []
  go []        r  =  go (reverse r) []
  go ((a,1):b) r  =  a : go b r
  go ((a,n):b) r  =  a : go b ((a,n-1):r)
```

With the `reverse` cost *amortized* over all the output this will add only a constant overhead per each output item.

Comment: I think you should apply your silly recursion workaround to something more like  Aplet123's pretty answer, or my optimized certain thereof.

Comment: I think _my_ way is pretty, with the rotation (and it's not workaround; it's exactly the same thing, up to the insignificant noise). re: that answer, when I saw `filter` I stopped reading. plus, recursion is forbidden by OP.

Comment: Your way is asymptotically slower! The `filter` is not optimal; my answer removes it.

Comment: Your way would be fine with a queue, but not a list.

Comment: that's Haskell's problem, not mine. I've found the algorithm, expressible within the confinement of the exercise's requirements, that's the point of it. you can implement circular buffer on top an array with some index juggling and wraparound for O(1) access and no-op rotation, if you care. shrinking is a bit harder though (only true un-linking of nodes with real pointers makes it linear). plus, repeated scan with filter is just as quadratic!

Comment: You didn't read that answer carefully enough. It performs one scan per *iteration*, but not one scan per *element*. It's linear in the size of the input plus the size of the output, which is optimal. And lists are lists; you can't make lazy lists that magically let you rotate efficiently.

Comment: yes, thanks, you're right, it *is* linear in the size of the output.  :)

Comment: @dfeuer OK so with explicit iteration it's `map fst . concatMap snd
 . takeWhile (not . null . snd)
 . tail . iterate (\ (i,xs) -> (i+1, filter (\x -> snd x > i) xs))
 . ((,) 0)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion to accomplish this:

```hs
lado :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
-- base case
lado [] = []
-- take each of the non-zero elements then recurse
lado xs = map fst nonzero ++ lado subtracted
    where
        -- find elements with non-zero count
        nonzero = filter (\x -> snd x > 0) xs
        -- subtract one from the count for each of those elements
        subtracted = map (\(x, n) -> (x, n - 1)) nonzero
```

Comment: I can't use recursion on this :\

Comment: I think this is very pretty. See my answer for an optimized implementation of this idea.

Comment: @dfeuer OK so this can be fixed with `lado xs = map fst xs ++ ...` plus one initial filter, and then it does fuse after removing the needless name `nonzero`, like in your answer which fuses the map and the filter into one list comprehension. or we remove the map altogether as in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64189254/output-an-element-the-number-of-times-i-want/64198227#comment113527466_64198227) elsewhere, here.

Comment: @dfeuer (my rotation idea was fusing the filtering and the mapping too, just inefficiently so)

Comment: @WillNess, the `map fst` should ideally be a list comprehension instead to avoid stupid thunks. Both this version and my modification can have (theoretical) space leaks. This can be fixed by replacing that `map fst` thing with one that forces the spine of the result of the recursive call rather carefully.

Comment: @dfeuer by something like ``map' f = foldr (\ x ys -> let y=f x in y `seq` y : ys) []``...? or does it have to be `pseq` to really have a *guarantee* that it works?

Comment: @WillNess, that doesn't look right. I'll write up what I mean for you tomorrow.

Comment: @WillNess, [here's what I mean](https://gist.github.com/treeowl/86dd2cd8fd0808626dbff52ea5146c7c).

Answer (score 1):

The [**`transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:transpose) of `[["A", "A", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["C"]]` is:

```
Prelude Data.List> transpose [["A", "A", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["C"]]
[["A","B","C"],["A","B"],["A"]]
```

if we then concatenate these with [**`concat :: [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:concat), we get:

```
Prelude Data.List> concat (transpose [["A", "A", "A"], ["B", "B"], ["C"]])
["A","B","C","A","B","A"]
```

if we can thus make a lists of three `"A"`s, two `"B"`s, and one `"C"`, then we can generate such list. I leave generating this list as an exercise. You can make use of [**`replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-List.html#v:replicate) and use list comprehension, or [**`map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map).

Comment: I can't use Data.List, so I don't think I can use transpose :\

Comment: @JohnSmith: the modules are [open source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#transpose).

Comment: Yeh, but I can only use functions from prelude on this exercise.

Comment: @JohnSmith: you can look at how it is implemented, and implement a helper function based on that...

Comment: Okok, just tell me 1 thing. I have this function  [take v (repeat n) | n <- numeros x y && v <- andares xs] . I know the && v <- andares xs is wrong, but is there a way to do something like this? Basically, the n and v go always "together" so it would be easy to do this.

Comment: @JohnSmith: based on the signature of the function in your question, you have a list of 2-tuples, so you can use `[ ... | (v, n) <- listoftwotupes ]`.

Comment: If you have two generators, you can use this in a nested way with `[take v (repeat n) | n <- numeros x y, v <- andares xs]` given `andares xs` returns a list of values, if it returns a single value, this is just `[take (andares xs) (repeat n) | n <- numeros x y]`.

Comment: I had legendaCampainha x y xs = [take v (repeat n) | n <- numeros x y, v <- andares xs] but the output is wrong:  > legendaCampainha 3 13 [("A",3),("B",2),("C",1)             
   -----------------------[[1,1,1],[1,1],[1],[2,2,2],[2,2],[2],[3,3,3],[3,3],[3]]  and i wanted this [[1,1,1],[2,2],[3] .

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about efficiency, you can make this work, I guess:

```
lado xs =
  [ str
    | i <- [1..maxCount]
    , (str, j) <- xs
    , j >= i ]
  where
    maxCount = maximum (map snd xs)
```

Comment: `lado [("A",3),("B",2),("C",1)]` ==> 
`["A","B","C","B","C","C"]`, which is wrong. according to the Q it should be `["A","B","C","A","B","A"]`.

Comment: @WillNess, I think I fixed it properly this time.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Aplet123](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189269/1477667)'s approach, but I *think* it can be made a bit more efficient. What's wrong with it as is? `nonzero` is used twice, which means the program will realize its result list rather than fusing it with the consumers of that list. So each time we go through the recursion, we'll allocate three new lists. Can we fix it? Let's start by assuming that the argument has no zeros in it.

```hs
-- Assumes all the Ints are positive
lado' :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
lado' [] = []
lado' xns = map fst xns ++ rest
  where
    rest = lado' [(x, n - 1) | (x, n) <- xns, n /= 1]
```

This is already much better. It only allocates two lists each time. But `map fst` will allocate a bunch of selector thunks to put in the list. We can fix that with another list comprehension:

```hs
-- Assumes all the Ints are positive
lado' :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
lado' [] = []
lado' xns = start ++ rest
  where
    start = [x | (x, _) <- xns]
    rest = lado' [(x, n - 1) | (x, n) <- xns, n /= 1]
```

Nice and clean! But what if the original list has zeros? We can filter it up front:

```hs
lado :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
lado = lado' . filter (\(_, n) -> n > 0)
```

There's still one little inefficiency in the case where there are a good number of non-tiny numbers: the representation of the list of pairs. A small improvement:

```
data IPair a = IPair a !Int
```

A bigger improvement would change the implementation of lists:

```
data IPList a
  = Cons a !Int (IPList a)
  | Nil
```

The downside of `IPList` is that you'd have to ditch list comprehensions.

I see you're not allowed to use recursion, which is ... quite a silly requirement. Can you see how to work around that with `iterate`, `takeWhile`, and `concat`?

Answer (score 1):

Will Ness came up with a nice expression in terms of rotations:

```hs
lado ::  [(a,Int)] -> [a]
lado []        = []
lado ((a,1):b) = a : lado b
lado ((a,n):b) = a : lado (b ++ [(a,n-1))])
```

Unfortunately, this will be quite inefficient because using `++` to add an element to the end of a list takes linear time. This can be fixed by using a *queue* instead of a list. The queue is used in an ephemeral manner, so it can be a very simple one:

```hs
-- Invariant: The Int is at least 1.
data IStream a
  = ISCons a !Int (IStream a)
  | ISNil

-- Invariant: The Int is at least 1.
data IList a
  = ICons a !Int !(IList a)
  | INil

data IQueue a = IQueue !(IStream a) !(IList a)

-- Note: the list may be infinite
listToIStream :: [(a, Int)] -> IStream a
listToIStream = foldr go ISNil
  where
    go (a, n) r
      | n <= 0 = r
      | otherwise = ISCons a n r

listToIQueue :: [(a, Int)] -> IQueue a
listToIQueue xs = IQueue (listToIStream xs) INil

dequeue :: IQueue a -> Maybe (Dequeued a)
dequeue (IQueue (ISCons a i more) rear) = Just (Dequeued a i (IQueue more rear))
dequeue (IQueue ISNil INil) = Nothing
dequeue (IQueue ISNil (ICons a i more)) = Just $! (rotate ISNil a i more)

data Dequeued a = Dequeued a !Int !(IQueue a)

rotate :: IStream a -> a -> Int -> IList a -> Dequeued a
rotate str a0 i0 INil = Dequeued a0 i0 (IQueue str INil)
rotate str a0 i0 (ICons a i more) = rotate (ISCons a0 i0 str) a i more

enqueue :: IQueue a -> a -> Int -> IQueue a
enqueue (IQueue front rear) a i = IQueue front (ICons a i rear)
```

Now we can define

```hs
lado :: [(a, Int)] -> [a]
lado = lado' . listToIQueue

lado' :: IQueue a -> [a]
lado' q = case dequeue q of
  Nothing -> []
  Just (Dequeued a 1 b) -> a : lado' b
  Just (Dequeued a n b) -> a : lado' (enqueue b a (n - 1))
```

Comment: that's deferred-reverse amortized queue a-la Okasaki. (I was expecting a corecursive queue like we did with the breadth-first traversals... that aside,) do we really need to juggle the three data types here? do we really need to be that precise? coding with lists and pairs is so common in a day-to-day simple-minded programming, is GHC really that incapable of handling this use case well and we really need to spend all this effort just to express so common an FP idiom as building a (decorated-data) list in reverse? :( JS doesn't expect this level of preciseness from its practitioners, (contd)

Comment: I think. JS is successful. I don't think these two are unrelated. /sigh

Comment: @WillNess, of course you can just use lists of pairs if you like. I just have trouble resisting the opportunity to squeeze out a little more performance through millioptimization.

Comment: @WillNess, this particular sort of queue predates Okasaki by a long time. His contribution was making the amortized bounds hold up persistently by rotating more often; we don't need that here.